# Making __dict__ A Property

Tags: python, datamodel, bunch

Why does this work:

```
class Bunch(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

b = Bunch()
b["a"] = 1
print(b.a)
```

Albeit with a circular reference:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
# ref count is 3 when normally it is 2
```

But not this:

```
class Bunch(dict):

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        return self

b = Bunch()
b["a"] = 1
b.a

# raises AttributeError
```

While `__dict__` is an attribute by most outward appearances, there's some special behavior being implemented behind the scenes which is bypassing the descriptor logic created by the `property`.

Comment: Think about `self.__dict__ = self`.  Obviously, that *can't* be equivalent to `self.__dict__['__dict__'] = self`, right?  So `self.__dict__` must be magic.

Comment: @OferSadan: No, function or not doesn't matter, and it's not quite a function in the second example anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `__dict__` attribute already basically *is* a property. (It's not literally a `property`, but it's implemented through the descriptor protocol, just like `property`.)

When you set `self.__dict__ = self`, that goes through the `__dict__` descriptor's `__set__` method and replaces the dict used for instance attributes.

However, Python doesn't use the `__dict__` descriptor to find the instance dict when performing attribute operations; it uses a different internal mechanism. Thus, creating your own `__dict__` descriptor doesn't affect the attribute lookup mechanism for `b.a` in your second example.